# How to do simple operation on elements of list which are data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have list, which every element of it is data frame.the dimension(number of rows) of data frames in every elelemnt of list is diffrent from each other,like as following :

```
for(i in 1:length(nm)){print(dim(ismr2[[i]]))}
[1] 510   3
[1] 477   3
[1] 412   3
[1] 422   3
[1] 455   3
[1] 398   3
[1] 405   3
[1] 407   3
[1] 452   3
[1] 462   3
[1] 498   3
[1] 495   3
[1] 469   3
[1] 470   3
```

But there is one rule, all row names are subset of the  row names of data frame with biggest rows number (for example 510 here).

My goal is to find the data frame with biggest rows number (let's call it refrence data frame) and add the other data frames those rows which are missing(rows which are in refrence data frame, but not in other data frame).

Expected output:

1) a list, which every element of it is data frame

2) all element of list which are data frame have same dimension. the dimension should equal to the dimention of the refrence data frame.(refrence data frame is the element of the list with largest row number)

3) rows which are newly added to the data frame to have same dimention, should have row name which are in refrence data frame and have 0 entry.

Here is my effort, but it doesn't work:

```
isomir2  # original list

ismr3 <- vector("list", length(isomir2))

# find the refrence data frame: it give me just the data fram with larget dimension, I don't know which data frame is it (which element of list) 
length.max <- max(unlist(lapply(isomir2, function(x) nrow(x))))

for (i in 1:length(isomir2)){
  ismr3[[i]] <- rbind(isomir2[[i]],matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=length.max - nrow(isomir2[[i]]))
                      temp <- rownames(isomir2[[i]])
                      rownames(P[[i]]) <- c(temp, # How should I find the missing row name here ? ))
}
```

Would someone help me to implement this ?

simple input :

```
> P
[[1]]
  [,1]
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4

[[2]]
  [,1]
A    1
B    2
D    3

[[3]]
  [,1]
B    1
C    2
```

Expected Output:

```
> P
[[1]]
  [,1]
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4

[[2]]
  [,1]
A    1
B    2
D    3
C    0

[[3]]
  [,1]
B    1
C    2
D    0
A    0
```

Comment: If there are no duplicates in the data: `dat <- do.call(rbind, ismr2); dat <- dat[!duplicated(dat),]`

Comment: Are you sure that data.frame have consistent rows? I mean lets say all rows in data.frame with 477 row are also there in data.frame with 510 rows? Plus what you wanted to do? Union?

Comment: Basically, at the end I want a list with the same length as original list. but every element of the list which are data frame should have same dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I generate some non-sense data on the form your data is on (since you didn't provide any example data set to work on)

```
ismr2 <- lapply(2*1:5, function(i){
    d <- data.frame(rnorm(i), runif(i))
    row.names(d) <- sample(LETTERS[1:i])
    d
})
```

I then *impute* the data frames of `ismr2` like this

```
ref <- ismr2[[which.max(sapply(ismr2, nrow))]]

ismr3 <- lapply(ismr2, function(x){
    rbind(x, ref[!rownames(ref) %in% rownames(x),])
})
```

Now all frames of `ismr3` have the same number of rows, named like this:

```
> sapply(ismr3, row.names)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,] "B"  "D"  "B"  "F"  "F" 
 [2,] "A"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "C" 
 [3,] "F"  "A"  "F"  "D"  "H" 
 [4,] "C"  "C"  "A"  "E"  "D" 
 [5,] "H"  "F"  "E"  "A"  "E" 
 [6,] "D"  "H"  "C"  "B"  "B" 
 [7,] "E"  "E"  "H"  "C"  "A" 
 [8,] "I"  "I"  "I"  "H"  "I" 
 [9,] "J"  "J"  "J"  "I"  "J" 
[10,] "G"  "G"  "G"  "J"  "G"
```

If you do not want to impute (i.e. take the missing rows from the refence frame) but instead  let them be `0` (or perhaps more appropriately `NA`?) you can do

```
lapply(ismr2, function(x){
    rn <- union(rownames(x), rownames(ref))
    x <- x[rn,]
    x[is.na(x)] <- 0  # Remove this line to let missing rows be NA
    rownames(x) <- rn
    x
})
```

Comment: it doesn't work. basically after runnig your code, all element of my list, which are data frame should have same row number.

Comment: The code works fine, so I suspect there is something is wrong with your data. Are all rows named as they should? Could you post a small exmaple data set for me and others to test our solutions on?

Comment: sure, all row names should come from the refrence data frame row name, and one thig is gonig  wrong ,  the new rows which you add, they should take value zero, I mean their coordinate should have zero value.

Comment: @Baklin, I added the example

Answer (score 0):

```
# if you dont care about row names
# this works for data.frames with multiple columns
# this does not add empty columns
l=list()
l[[1]]=data.frame(1:4) # note that double [[]] are important else it will be stored as a         vector or list in list instead of data.frame in list
l[[2]]=data.frame(1:3)
l[[3]]=data.frame(1:2)
l[[4]]=data.frame(1:4)

# check biggest
size=0
for(i in 1:length(l)){
  if (dim(l[[i]])[1]>size) {
    size=dim(l[[i]])[1]
  }
}

# add empty rows
emptyValue=0
for(i in 1:length(l)){
  if(dim(l[[i]])[1]<size){
    l[[i]][dim(l[[i]])[1]:size,]=emptyValue
  }
}
l
```

speed can be improved by changing the "for"s in "lapply"s